# I am trying to show data in table but i am facing this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, fetch, use-effect, mern

I am trying to show data in table but i am facing following error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"
Any kind of help would really be appreciated.
When I am trying to bind the data in the map an error is being shown. In short, map function is not properly working
Following is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import '../StockPage/Stock.css'
import '../StockPage/stockValidation'
import { useFormik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios"


function Stock() {
    const [item, setItems] = useState({
        itemName: "",
        itemCatagory: "",
        itemPrice: "",
        stockAmount: ""
    })
    const [search,setSearch] =useState('');
    const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState()

    // On Page load display all records 
    const loadItemsDetail = async () => {
        const response = fetch('http://localhost:4000/stock/list')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (myJson) {
                setAllItems(myJson);
            });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        loadItemsDetail();
    }, []);

    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setItems({
            ...item,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    const itemSubmit = () => {

        const { itemName, itemCatagory, itemPrice, stockAmount } = item
        if (itemName && itemCatagory && itemPrice && stockAmount) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:4000/stock", item)
                .then(res => console.log(res))
        }
        else {
            alert("Invalid inputs")
        }

    }
      // Search Records here 
      const searchRecords = () =>
      {
          alert(search)
          axios.get(``)
          .then(response => {
            setAllItems(response.data);
          });
      }
       // Delete Employee Record
       const deleteRecord = (productId) =>
       {
         axios.delete(``)
         .then((result)=>{
            loadItemsDetail();
         })
         .catch(()=>{
           alert('Error in the Code');
         });
       };

    return (
        <div className="Stock">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {/* insert area */}
                    <div className="col-lg-4">
                        <h4 className='text-center ml-4 mb-5'>Create New Records</h4>
                        {console.log("Item", item)}
                        {/* <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}> */}
                        <div>
                            <div className="mx-auto w-75 ">
                                <div className="form-group ">
                                    <label htmlFor="itemName">Item Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="id_itemName" name="itemName" value={item.itemName} onChange={handleChange}
                                        placeholder="Item Name" />

                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group ">
                                    <label htmlFor="itemCategory">Item Category</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="id_itemCategory" name="itemCatagory" value={item.itemCatagory} onChange={handleChange}
                                        placeholder="Item Category" />

                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="itemPrice">Item Price</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="id_itemPrice" name="itemPrice" value={item.itemPrice} onChange={handleChange}
                                        placeholder="Item Price" />

                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="stockAmount">Stock Amount</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="id_Amount" name="stockAmount" value={item.stockAmount} onChange={handleChange}
                                        placeholder="Amount" />

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='text-center mt-4'>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={itemSubmit}>Enter</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* detailed area */}
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h5 class="text-center  ml-4 mt-4  mb-5">View Records</h5>
                        <div class="input-group mb-4 mt-3">
                            <div class="form-outline">
                                <input type="text" id="form1" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} class="form-control" placeholder="Search Employee Here" style={{ backgroundColor: "#ececec" }} />
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" onClick={searchRecords} class="btn btn-success">
                                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-hover  table-striped table-bordered ml-4 ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                              
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Item Price</th>
                                <th>Item Amount</th>
                                <th>Action</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {console.log(allItems)}
                                {allItems.map((name) =>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{name.itemName}</td>
                                        <td>{name.itemCatagory}</td>
                                        <td>{name.itemPrice}</td>
                                        <td>{name.stockAmount}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a className="text-danger mr-2"
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                    const confirmBox = window.confirm(
                                                        "Do you really want to delete " + name.itemName
                                                    )
                                                    if (confirmBox === true) {
                                                        deleteRecord(name.id)
                                                    }
                                                }}> <i class="far fa-trash-alt" style={{ fontSize: "18px", marginRight: "5px" }}></i> </a>

                                            <Link class=" mr-2" to={`/EditEmployee/editID/${name.id}`}>
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </Link>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Stock;
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jzqY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give an empty array(`[]`) default state to `allItems` like below.

```
const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState([]);
```

Comment: I did now it's showing allItems.map is not a function

Comment: can you check what's the output of `console.log(myJson)`? it's not an array I guess

Comment: Did you get this solve? Am running into the error as well @ZaryabKhan